# How to compare date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, sencha-touch

I suppose my question is simple but  I am  not finding the solution, How to compare a date with the previous or minor or the next date?

At the moment I have this code:

```
if(newDate > oldDate || newDate < oldDate){}
```

And its working but Its nasty, I tried `newDate != oldDate`  but it doesn´t work for me, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to check this answer.

Comparing 2 JavaScript dates.

[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use the date timestamp to compare the dates, like this:-

```
var oldDate = new Date('2013-05-23');
var newDate = new Date('2013-05-24');

if(newDate.getTime() > oldDate.getTime()) {
 console.log("Old date is the past date");
}
```

Note:- Higher timestamp value(number) denotes latest date. So timestamp of `yesterday` is less than the timestamp of `today`.